# My EPSON ET-2710 printer has a USB connection with a GNOME managed computer. I can print documents but Image Scan ignores my connection to the printer

Tags: gnome3, printer, scanner, connectivity

My computer is a recent ACER Aspire with GNOME environment. I have connected it to my ET 2710 EPSON printer through a USB connection.
No problem to print a document. But the connection to the computer does not appear and when I try to connect EPSON Image Scan I downloaded, it does not find any scanner...
What should I do ?

Answer (score 1):

You need a scanner driver. They usually are shipped separately or not shipped at all and needed to be downloaded from the official web-site

Go to http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/

Type your printer name, choose OS, and look at the bottom of the list of available drivers.